# Want to replace Unicode characters from my output

Tags: android

I'm creating program where I can parse XML data from server. I'm getting the response from server but the output contains Unicode.

I'm attaching my code below

```
package com.example.rsdevteam.xmlparsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    URL url=null;
    HttpURLConnection con=null;
    String u="http://charts.jmfonline.in/OMSRouter/OrderRouter.svc/LedgBal_3";
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        String param=null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try
            {
                url=new URL(u);

                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setDoInput(true);

                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                JSONObject param   = new JSONObject();

                param.put("SrvName","");
                param.put("MethodName","");
                param.put("Parameters","08 Mar 2017|07 Apr 2017|1|1|1|10112829|0|");

                OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                os.write(param.toString());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    br.close();

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
"<NewDataSet>\u000d\u000a  <Table>\u000d\u000a    <RowSeg1>1<\/RowSeg1>\u000d\u000a    <RowSeg>1<\/RowSeg>\u000d\u000a    <Exchange>NSE<\/Exchange>\u000d\u000a    <Segment>CAPITAL<\/Segment>\u000d\u000a    <CltCode>10112829  <\/CltCode>\u000d\u000a    <CLTNAME>MEHUL ULLHAS PARIKH<\/CLTNAME>\u000d\u000a    <ClientCodeAndName>MEHUL ULLHAS PARIKH ( 10112829   ) <\/ClientCodeAndName>\u000d\u000a    <DATE>2017-03-08T00:00:00+05:30<\/DATE>\u000d\u000a    <Vtype>18<\/Vtype>\u000d\u000a    <SHORTDESC>OPENEN<\/SHORTDESC>\u000d\u000a    <Particular>Opening balance<\/Particular>\u000d\u000a    <VoucherNumber \/>\u000d\u000a    <Debit>0.00<\/Debit>\u000d\u000a    <Credit>28.04<\/Credit>\u000d\u000a    <OpeningBalance>-28.04<\/OpeningBalance>\u000d\u000a    <Running_x0020_Balance>28.04<\/Running_x0020_Balance>\u000d\u000a    <ChequeNumber \/>\u000d\u000a  <\/Table>\u000d\u000a  <Table>\u000d\u000a    <RowSeg1>2<\/RowSeg1>\u000d\u000a    <RowSeg>2<\/RowSeg>\u000d\u000a    <Exchange>NSE<\/Exchange>\u000d\u000a    <Segment>CAPITAL<\/Segment>\u000d\u000a    <CltCode>10112829  <\/CltCode>\u000d\u000a    <CLTNAME>MEHUL ULLHAS PARIKH<\/CLTNAME>\u000d\u000a    <ClientCodeAndName>MEHUL ULLHAS PARIKH ( 10112829   ) <\/ClientCodeAndName>\u000d\u000a    <DATE>2017-03-17T00:00:00+05:30<\/DATE>\u000d\u000a    <Vtype>3<\/Vtype>\u000d\u000a    <SHORTDESC>PAYBNK<\/SHORTDESC>\u000d\u000a    <Particular>QUARTERLY SETTLEMENT - R<\/Particular>\u000d\u000a    <VoucherNumber>201600138689<\/VoucherNumber>\u000d\u000a    <Debit>28.04<\/Debit>\u000d\u000a    <Credit>0.00<\/Credit>\u000d\u000a    <OpeningBalance>-28.04<\/OpeningBalance>\u000d\u000a    <Running_x0020_Balance>0.00<\/Running_x0020_Balance>\u000d\u000a    <ChequeNumber>4440U17077872233<\/ChequeNumber>\u000d\u000a  <\/Table>\u000d\u000a  <Table>\u000d\u000a    <RowSeg1>3<\/RowSeg1>\u000d\u000a    <RowSeg>3<\/RowSeg>\u000d\u000a    <Exchange>NSE<\/Exchange>\u000d\u000a    <Segment>CAPITAL<\/Segment>\u000d\u000a    <CltCode>10112829  <\/CltCode>\u000d\u000a    <CLTNAME>MEHUL ULLHAS PARIKH<\/CLTNAME>\u000d\u000a    <ClientCodeAndName>MEHUL ULLHAS PARIKH ( 10112829   ) <\/ClientCodeAndName>\u000d\u000a    <DATE>2017-03-21T00:00:00+05:30<\/DATE>\u000d\u000a    <Vtype>2<\/Vtype>\u000d\u000a    <SHORTDESC>REPBNK<\/SHORTDESC>\u000d\u000a    <Particular>ONLINE PAYIN<\/Particular>\u000d\u000a    <VoucherNumber>201600103155<\/VoucherNumber>\u000d\u000a    <Debit>0.00<\/Debit>\u000d\u000a    <Credit>50.00<\/Credit>\u000d\u000a    <OpeningBalance>-28.04<\/OpeningBalance>\u000d\u000a    <Running_x0020_Balance>50.00<\/Running_x0020_Balance>\u000d\u000a    <ChequeNumber>1172615900<\/ChequeNumber>\u000d\u000a  <\/Table>\u000d\u000a<\/NewDataSet>"
```

`/u000d/u000a` this should be removed and all the tags are closing like `<\/TAG_NAME>`, but the tag should be enclose like `</TAG_Name>`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(your_string);`

You can find the jar file at: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachecommonslangjar.htm